# How to inject dependencies to a laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm adding a laravel job to my queue from my controller as such

```
$this->dispatchFromArray(
    'ExportCustomersSearchJob',
    [
        'userId' => $id,
        'clientId' => $clientId
    ]
);
```

I would like to inject the `userRepository` as a dependency when implementing the `ExportCustomersSearchJob` class. Please how can I do that?

I have this but it doesn't work

```
class ExportCustomersSearchJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    private $userId;

    private $clientId;

    private $userRepository;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId, $clientId, $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You inject your dependencies in the `handle` method:

```
class ExportCustomersSearchJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    private $userId;

    private $clientId;

    public function __construct($userId, $clientId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->clientId = $clientId;
    }

    public function handle(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        // use $repository here...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have a parent job class with a `handle` method and child job classes that have a `run` method that is invoked from the parent's `handle` method? I want to be able to type hint a repository in my child job class in the `run` method but then I would get an error in parent class about `too few arguments`.

Comment: Just use inheritance. Typehint ALL the classes you need at the outher-most child job, and pass the objects down to the parent classes. For example your child job may have this `handle(UserRepository $repository, FooService $fooService)` and starts by passing `FooService` to the parent: `parent::__handle($fooService)`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is wondering how to inject dependency into `handle` function:

put the following in a service provider

```
$this->app->bindMethod(ExportCustomersSearchJob::class.'@handle', function ($job, $app) {
    return $job->handle($app->make(UserRepository::class));
});
```

[laravel documentation for job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#class-structure)

Comment: Laravel does this for you automatically when you use the `dispatch()` function. There is no need to manually bind dependencies.

Comment: is that the new feature after laravel 5?

Comment: This is how it has worked *since* version 5. Documentation shows injection through the service container here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#basic-usage So long as a class or service is register in the service container, then Laravel will automatically inject it into the `handle()` method. The same works for HTTP controller methods.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel v5 and after.**

Since Laravel v5, dependencies in jobs are handled by themselves.
The documentation reads

> "You may type-hint any dependencies you need on the handle method and the service container will automatically inject them"

So, now, all you have to do in the handle method of the Job is to add the dependencies you want to use. For example:

```
use From/where/ever/UserRepository;

class test implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
//
    }

    public function handle(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
//        $userRepository can be used now.
    }
}
```