# Constructor Dependency Injection without passing when instantiating

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Using Laravel, I have a job with the following constructor:

```
public function __construct($accountId, DirectDebitInterface $directDebit)
{
    $this->accountId = $accountId;
    $this->directDebit = $directDebit;
}
```

When I dispatch this job:

```
CreateDirectDebitAccount::dispatch($accountId);
```

It will throw an error due to missing parameters of the constructor (the interface).

This of course makes sense, but is there a way for me to use the dependency injection without passing it into the constructor when dispatching?

I know I can drop the DI and just use:

```
$this->directDebit = App::make(XXX);
```

But I'm trying to understand the usage of DI etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject dependencies to a laravel job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457639/how-to-inject-dependencies-to-a-laravel-job)

Comment: @Peppermintology Certainly does!